# Map displays only the world location on device

Tags: android, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing my application for Android Environment using IBM Worklight and the following Library: http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html

Whenever I enter any location from the textbox, I am getting the world map, not the location which I entered. I need to zoom in to see the exact location. It is working correctly on Worklight Console. But on device, Whenever I enter any city name, I am getting only world map. There is not any error on LogCat.

Also, I am getting two alerts continuously.

1. "Rate Limit Exceeded"
2. "The SQL Query is malformed. (there might be something wrong with these URL parameters: select, Where, orderBy, intersects)."

The following is HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>testeApp</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
         minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <!--  
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
        -->
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.3.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
          src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gme.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/store-locator.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/storelocator.css">
        <script src="js/medicare-static-ds.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


         <style type="text/css">
          body { font-family: sans-serif; }
          #map-canvas, #panel { height: 500px; }
          #panel { width: 300px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
           p.attribution, p.attribution a { color: #666; }
         </style>
</head>

  <body>
        <div data-role="page" >
            <div data-role="content">
               <div id="panel" class="storelocator-panel" style="width : 100% ; height : 30%; " >   

            <form class="storelocator-filter" >

            <div class="location-search" id="locationSearch" style="height :35%; ">

            </div>

            <div class="feature-filter">
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div id="map-canvas" >
            </div>      

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

The following is the javascript code for the Map.

```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.67023, -79.38676),
        zoom: 4,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');

  var data = new storeLocator.GMEDataFeed({
  tableId: '12421761926155747447-06672618218968397709',
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyAtunhRg0VTElV-P7n4Agpm9tYlABQDCAM',
  propertiesModifier: function(props) {
  var shop = ([props.NAME]);
  var locality = join([props.CITY, props.POSTAL_CODE], ', ');

  return {
    id: props.STORE,
    title: props.NAME,
    address: join([shop, props.ADDRESS, locality], '<br>'),

     };
  }
  });

   var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data, {
      geolocation: false

    });

        new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
      view: view
      });
     });


     function join(arr, sep) {
      var parts = [];
         for (var i = 0, ii = arr.length; i < ii; i++) {
            arr[i] && parts.push(arr[i]);
            }
          return parts.join(sep);
      }
```

Comment: There is no way to recreate this - provide your Worklight project.

Comment: Here is the test application. If I enter any city name (Toronto), I  am getting the world map only. https://db.tt/v6Ci3dxz

Comment: I am getting the "rate limit exceeded" and "no zooming to location" issues in both preview and device.

Answer (score 0):

For the zoom issue, to get to street-level zooming, I use `zoom: 18`.

As for the "rate limit exceeded" warning, this warning is issued by Google Maps and you need to verify your usage of Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

Comment: If I select the city name(Toronto ON, Canada) from the suggestion provided in textbox,I am still getting the world map only. Also I keep on getting the alert for sql which is "The SQL Query is malformed. (there might be something wrong with these URL parameters: select, Where, orderBy, intersects)." Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't experience that, so I can't.